# WAP Assigns same IP addresses for 2 or more devices occasionally

Tags: ip, wifi, ip-address

I am new to being a sysadmin and am still learning so apologies if I say anything incorrect or flat out wrong.

Where I work we have a wifi network consisting of several different WAPs that spread the wifi out over the entire building. These WAPS are all cheap and nasty budget ones that use the same SSID and passkey to generate the wifi.

The issue we are having is that they seem to assign different devices the same IP which causes a conflict and neither of them can connect to the web. This happens most notably on mobile phones.
The only fix for this I have found so far is resetting the WAP's every week which seems to "reset" the IP addresses given and give new ones that are different.

I was told by a friend that this could be caused by phones requesting the same IP address when they re-connect to the wifi and then if 2 phones request the same one it causes the issue. But I haven't found any information on that online.

We have a DHCP server that assigns the IP addresses and the range is 192.1.1.10 to 192.1.1.100.
I probably expect around 50 devices to connect to the wifi at any one time give or take 10 or so.

So my questions are these:

- Does purchasing of higher end WAP's would fix this issue?
- And if not how could I go about finding a solution?

Comment: " These WAPS are all cheap and nasty budget ones that use the same SSID and passkey to generate the wifi." - this is not cheap, this is incompetence. The cost of a PROFESSIONAL WIP is below 50 USD for low end and all of them can run a coordinator - someone just bought without his brain and set it up violating best practices. Do NOT blame chepa here. Look up Mikrotik for CHEAP (Mikrotik HAP) and yes, you can run a manager on them (free) to coordinate. You do not need "higher end", you need "not braindead".

Comment: @TomTom Thanks for the reply. I am new to this role and these were here before i joined. I will look up the ones your suggested thank you.

Comment: This has been edited to make it more focused. Could this be re-opened at all ?

Answer (score 3):

Normally you should really only have one device on the network assigning IP addresses in a given range, If you can't do this then your WAPs need to be configured to have different none overlapping ranges.

e.g. if you whole network is using 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 as it's subnet then the WAPs should have:

- WAP 1 192.168.1.1-50
- WAP 2 192.168.1.51-100
- WAP 3 192.168.1.101-150

Buying new WAPs is only going to fix this if you end up with a fully centrally managed solution that includes the network definition and a central DHCP server (e.g. a Unifi network controller)

Comment: We do have a central DHCP server. Thats what assigns the IP addresses, and we have a set range of IP's it is allowed to assign. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Then if you are getting multiple devices with the same IP addresses, the DHCP server is not configured properly, it is very unlikely to have anything with the WAPs. Edit the question to add more details (e.g. how large is the address pool, how many devices you expect to connect and how long the lease times are)